# Session destroy not working in server after removing index.php in Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, session

My site doesn't log out, session destroy is not working after removing `index.php` from `.htaccess` in Codeigniter. It is working in localhost but not on the server.

### logout function

```
 function logout() {
    if ($this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in')) {
        $useremail = $this->session->userdata('username');
        $data = array(
                'username' => $useremail,
                'admin_logged_in' => true,
                'logged_in' =>true
            );
        $this->session->unset_userdata($data);
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('login');
    }
```

### .htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt) 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Try with remove `resources` with this line `RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|robots.txt) `

Comment: removing that line didn't worked. THank you for reponse.

Comment: before it work without removing index.php???